# fine-uploader multi-file upload example pure javascript

Tags: fine-uploader

On the project page, it states that multi-file uploads are possible with fine-uploader.

What parameter needs to be set to make this possible?

Is there an example with progress bars?

Comment: In the future, please use the "fine-uploader" tag for Fine Uploader questions.  Fine Uploader developers monitor this tag.  I only happened to find your question doing a search for questions mentioning "fine-uploader".

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needs to be set to make this possible.  By default, Fine Uploader supports the `multiple` attribute on file input elements.  You should be able to select multiple files without setting any related options.

Note that IE9 and older do not support multiple file selection, nor does Android.